# Dumping schema over the network

Tags: mysql

This seems like a stupid question but... I am trying to dump mysql database schema over the network, and `mysqldump --no-data ...` seems to take about 3 minutes to dump my 100 tables.  If I do this on the server locally, it takes 3 seconds.

Is there any way to use mysqldump to dump the schema over the network, but speed it up?
Thanks,

Comment: What kind of network environment you have? How big your database is? Your question lacks details.

Comment: I am going over a vpn connection from one datacenter to another, and ping time is about 50 msec.  I am not sure if the size of database matters here... the size of my schema is about 100 tables and 10 columns in each on average.

Answer (score 2):

You can compress the stream, but that may not help a whole lot. Why are you surprised that things take longer over the network? Speed up your network and/or speed up the device you're dumping to if you want to try and improve performance.

Comment: I am not surprised that it takes longer over the network.  I wonder if there is a way to batch this somehow

Comment: That's not going to speed it up. You can dump locally and them copy over the network in a second step, though.